# Mongodb find() takes 1 second

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection named "restaurants" in my mongodb database.

This collection has only one document

The problem is when I fetch it using mongoose, by `Model.find({restaurantUid})`, it takes about `1 second` to fetch it.

This restaurant document has about 140 products(foods) in it, and I have an array of these products n x n, a table, in order to track which food is selected by which food. The document size is about 3Mb.

Could you suggest me a way to decrease this fetching time?

I really don't think the problem is about indexing, since I have only one document in my collection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using **Mongoose** for your application, your code can be look like this for faster performance...

```
Model.findById(_id)
     .lean()
     .exec(function (err, doc) {
     //handle error and results
});
```

1. `Model.findById(_id)` instead of `Model.find()`. Because, the `_id` is cast based on the **Schema** before sending the command.
   Reference: [mongoosejs doc for findById()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)
2. `Query.prototype.lean()` which returns plain javascript objects and give high-performance for read-only scenarios.
   reference: [mongoosejs doc for lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)

Also follow these discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/u2_DzDydcnA/discussion

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, there is no way to make the fetching faster, i mean you could use some cloud database service like "MongoDB Altas", and buy a good plan so you can have a better server connection and hope for the best?.

Im guessing you have your mongo database running locally on your PC, and i dont think you can speed up that procces.

Im not sure what is your problem exactly, do you have this get request to the database as an async function??, so you can give the server time to load up all the products and then print the table.

Comment: The database is running on a remote server. The problem is when my user application try to get these products, they wait too much.